# Simple if/elif/else bash program with READ

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

The following code always ends up in the `else` part - also if I enter "peter" or "root". I do not get a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Hello World bash script
echo "What is your name?"
READ answer
if [ "$answer" == "root" ] 
    then
        echo "Hello Administrator"
    elif [ "$answer" == "peter" ] 
        then
            echo "Hello Peter"
    else
        echo "Hello User"
fi
```

Comment: Standard troubleshooting recommendation: put `set -x` before the problem section, and the shell will print what it's executing and you can see what's different from what you expected. (Though it can be confusing, because it prints something equivalent to what it's executing, and it sometimes picks an unexpected equivalent form for commands.) BTW, inside `[ ]`, you should use a single `=` for comparison; bash allows `==`, but it's not standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `READ answer`. Most likely you wanted `read answer`, which works as expected. You seem to have set up an alias called `READ`, that does soemthing different.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem :)